# How to Plot String DateTime From txt File

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have a code that writes the **datetime.datetime.now()** in txt file so it must be string value then i want to plot the date times but when I use Matplotlib it said string can not be converted to float 
so My question is How can i load txt file and plot the string datetime ?

here is my txt example :

```
2018-11-27 21:00:41 
2018-11-27 21:00:43 
2018-11-27 21:00:43 
2018-11-27 21:00:44 
2018-11-27 21:00:44 
2018-11-27 21:00:45 
2018-11-27 21:00:45 
2018-11-27 21:00:46 
2018-11-27 21:00:47 
2018-11-27 21:00:47 
2018-11-27 21:00:48
```

**EDIT :**
This is the loading and plotting code :

```
       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
       with open("mmmm.txt") as m:
            for line in m:
               m_float = map(float,line.split())
               plt.plot(m_float,'bo')
               plt.ylabel('FLOC - % of line')
               plt.xlabel('Sample Number')
               plt.axis([-10,10,0,5])
            plt.show()
```

Comment: why to float? and where is the datapoint corresponding to the time? Please show your file-loading and plotting code attempts as [mcve]

Comment: @PatrickArtner I want to write y-axis the 24H time and the x-axis date time